# Equivalent definitions of field norm for number fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

If $K$ is a field extension with degree $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then there are precisely $n$ field embeddings $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$ of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$, and we define the field norm $N^K_\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in K$ as the product:
$$ N^K_\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(\alpha) $$
It can be shown that $N^K_\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\in \mathbb{Q}$ and, in particular, if $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K$ then $N^K_\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\in \mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, if $L$ is a degree $n = [L:K]$ extension over $K$, then there are $n$ field embeddings $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ of $L$ into $\mathbb{C}$ that fix $K$ pointwise. We define the relative norm of $N^L_K(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in L$ in the same way: $$ N^L_K(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(\alpha) $$
It can be shown in a similar way that $N^L_K(\alpha) \in K$ with $N^L_K(\alpha)\in \mathcal{O}_K$ if $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_L$.

**My question is this:** If $L$ is Galois over $K$ (resp. $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$) I often see an alternative definition of the norm defined as:
$$ N^L_K(\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma\in \text{Gal}(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha) $$
Now, I can believe that the Galois automorphisms of $L$ over $K$ correspond to its field embeddings that fix $K$ pointwise. But how would one show that the two definitions of norm output the same number (i.e. they are actually equivalent)?

Comment: It's annoying to match things up because you haven't assumed that $K$ is Galois; the first definition produces a complex number that happens to lie in a particular copy of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and the second definition produces an element of $K$ with no ambiguity. Up to this ambiguity the idea is that if $L/K$ is Galois then the Galois group acts freely and transitively on the field embeddings that fix $K$.

Comment: Neither of these definitions is maximally clean and general; for that you should define the norm to be the determinant of multiplication by $\alpha$ acting on $L$ regarded as a vector space over $K$. No need to embed into a larger field and no Galois assumption, correctly reduces to both of these as special cases. We don't even need to assume that $L$ is a field!